# Bootstrap Carousal in React Component : not working

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-carousel

I am using 'create-react-app' to develop e web application. I am using Context API to get the data to this component, named Carousal.js

From the bootstrap for React, but my images are not showing up in the carousal. I tried testing if the image is rendering by putting

I am not getting what am I doing wrong? ** img and img2 are from the context API

My code is below:

```
export default class Details extends Component {
      render() {
           return (
            <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
              <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
              </ol>
              <div className="carousel-inner">
                <div className="carousel-item">
                  <img className="d-block w-100" src={img} alt="Second slide"/>
                  
                </div>
                <div className="carousel-item">
                  <img className="d-block w-100" src={img2} alt="Third slide"/>
                </div>
              </div>
              <a className="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                <span className="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span className="sr-only">Previous</span>
              </a>
              <a className="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
                <span className="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span className="sr-only">Next</span>
              </a>
        </div>
      )
    }}
```

Comment: is this code inside the render section? can you share the other codes, you can also console.log the img and img2 to check the vals

Comment: I did console.log and its rendering correctly. the code is inside the render function. I have edited the code above. please have a look.

Comment: Do your images work if you hard code them?

Comment: it does! it works if I hard code them

Comment: how are you getting the img data from the context? is it like this: let img = this.context;

Comment: My context has few other values like: title, id, price and image. I am using 'Consumer' to get the values from data.js .

In my render function I am rendering the title, id, price successfully. Image is also rendering if I do 
<img src={img} className="img-fluid" alt="" />
only inside the Carousal the image is not rendering !

Does this info help to answer the question? i need to make the carousel work :(